# NullPointerException error when using ModelDriven

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I have two classes as following

```
Address
  int ID
  int unit
  String street 

User 
    int ID 
    String Name
    Address address
```

my user class

```
public class user{
    .....
    private Address address;
     ...getters setters...
}
```

As shown above User class has an object of Address class in it. My code is expected to receive the values of a form and show them on console.

But when I try to access the unit attribute of address class it shows the following error.

"SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException"

my controller

```
@Action
class myclass implements ModelDriven{

   private User user = new User();

   public Register(){
       System.out.println("User's Unit" + user.getAddress().getUnit()); // error is on this line
   }
     @Override
    public Object getModel() {
       return user;
    }
```

jsp file

```
<s:form action="Register">
             <s:textfield name="name" label="Name"/>
             <s:textfield name="unit" label="Unit"/>
             <s:textfield name="block" label="Block"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: where exactly do you want to use your OTHER class attributes?

Comment: @R.J I need to have access to them in my controller to send them to my model to be saved on database.

Comment: **System.out.println("User's Unit" + user.getAddress().getUnit());** - you've already used it. Your question is still too vague.

Comment: @R.J, I used that as shown on question but it runs into error, I have also updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the following mate

```
<s:textfield name="address.unit" label="Unit"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this action class this will definitly work

```
public class myclass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>, Preparable{

    private User user = new User();

@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    user=new User();
}

@Override
public User getModel() {
    return user;
}
public Register(){
   System.out.println("User's Unit" + user.getAddress().getUnit()); 
   }
}
```

and change the jsp

```
<s:textfield name="address.unit" label="Unit"/>
```

for setting only unit property

Answer (score 1):

```
 <s:textfield name="name" label="Name"/>
```

Here struts2 will search for **name="name"**  property in the related DTO's in your respective action, but value-stack will failed to find the property named **"name"** in your action, because you have created a different bean class Address which is having  member "name". 
  So you have to tell your form-element that **"name"** instance resides in different POJO
i.e. **Adderess** . So make changes like this:

```
<s:textfield name="address.name" label="name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem as I see it is, you've not `new`d `address` object

`address = new Address();` in the constructor of `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you created the user object using "private User user = new User()" the address object of the user is not initialized. 
As user.getAddress() is null, when you try to invoke user.getAddress().getUnit() it will result in null pointer exception